# How can I correctly use the if(and()) function so that I can then drag it down alongside a column of numbers? (Google Sheets)

Tags: function, if-statement, google-sheets, nested, formula

I use Google Sheets and I have tried to get this formula right for a while now but it always gives me "Undefined" for every cell I drag down to along a column of data.

If you're curious, this is for stocks' Relative Strength Index (RSI) – buying & selling rates.

Some number examples (down a column, starting with A1) are as follows:

- 15
- 26
- 44
- 67
- 81
- 60

How can I readjust this so that the following formula works? It goes down column B alongside column A (where the data is)!

```
=IF(AND(0<=$A1,$A1<20),"Risky",

IF(AND(20<=$A1,$A1<40),"Oversold",

IF(AND(40<=$A1,$A1<60),"Neutral",

IF(AND(60<=$A1,$A1<80),"Overbought",

IF(AND(80<=$A1,$A1<=100),"Too Risky","Undefined")))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete everything in your column and use in row 1:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A, 
 {0, "Risky";
  20, "Oversold";
  40, "Neutral";
  60, "Overbought";
  80, "Too Risky";
  101, "Undefined"}, 2, 1)))
```

---

## update:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B*1, 
 {0, "Risky";
  20, "Oversold";
  40, "Neutral";
  60, "Overbought";
  80, "Too Risky";
  101, "Undefined"}, 2, 1))))
```

[image]

also see: **https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123729/186471**

Comment: Do you think you could keep it as a column somehow? Also, I think I figured that since I'm scraping the data, this could be the issue. Harun24HR's suggestion works, but not with the following formula: =SUBSTITUTE(index(IMPORTHTML("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="AMD","table", 9),9,10),"*","")

Comment: @wheresjohnnywalker answer updated. see your sheet

Comment: Perfect help! RSI is covered. I added a tab for Market Cap to the working example but it's giving me a Value error...where did I make a mistake?

Comment: @wheresjohnnywalker https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sX1d.png

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula-

```
=IFS(AND(A1>=0,A1<20),"Risky",AND(A1>=20,A1<40),"Oversold",AND(A1>=40,A1<60),"Neutral",AND(A1>=60,A1<80),"Overbought",AND(A1>=80,A1<=100),"Too Risky",A1>100,"Undefined")
```

[image]

Comment: It works, thank you! My numbers are scraped so the cell contains a formula but projects a number. Do you think this could be the issue of why the results are undefined? If so, how could I fix the issue?

Comment: Can you share sample google-sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EHUun4OukpK3_haM3Jr0pi2vlcxinP4zdBA6hOP9bq8/edit?usp=sharing